# check if specific plugin install in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, eclipse-plugin

I wrote a new plugin to Eclipse,  and also installed it.
Now- I want to check programmatically (C++ via QT) if the plugin was installed correctly.
so I want to find a way to retrieve all the plugins that installed on my eclipse.
any idea?

Comment: This is straightforward in a Java plugin, not sure how you would go about it in any other language.

Comment: @greg-449 but maybe this information is in specific file in the Eclipse folder. But i dont know where. (I'm sure that Eclipse not invents this information and take it from somewhere ...

Comment: Well yes, the information is in the `p2` directory in the installation, but dealing with these files without the p2 support code is hard work.

Comment: @greg-449, I don't think that it is the right folder. because I cannot find the in it one of the plugins I saw in the Eclipse list.... any idea?

Comment: The information about installed plugins is definitely in the p2 directory. One of the main lists is in the `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/xxx.profile` subdirectory in a `gz` compressed file.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449. now it is work for me. Can you please take a look also on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24311143/1851094 ?

Answer (score 0):

in Eclipse go to Help menu, click About Eclipse, Installation Details and click the plugins tab. That should get you an overview.

Comment: Yes, I know it. (and also saw my plugins in this list. But I want to do that programmatically (C++). do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: ah right, understood your question wrong than :) sorry about that.