# How to get the "available software sites" in eclipse programmatically

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, eclipse-cdt

I want to check in which "available software sites" is installed in my eclipse. (for example- check is CDT installed on my eclipse) through C++ via QT.

I know how to do that from eclipse (Help -> install new software -> available software sites link - http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-p2-siteprefs.htm).
But I don't know how to do that from c++ code...
Any idea please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the data for this is in a subdirectory of the `p2` directory in the Eclipse installation.

The subdirectory `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/xxx.profile/.data/.settings` contains the files `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.prefs` and `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.prefs` both of which seem to have available update site information.

The xxx.prefs files are Java 'properties' files and will have to be read by something that understands that format, including the special character escaping and Unicode encoding.

Comment: Thanks a lot @greg-449 !!!
Do you know where I can find the way how to parse those files?

Comment: I don't use C++ these days. Note that Eclipse has a command line interface for doing many p2 install related operations.

Comment: Do you mean to this link: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_director.html ?

Comment: Yes that whole section on the 'Provisioning Platform'